# How to move vertexes in opposite directions

Tags: vertices

Honestly, I used to know how to do this but I have completely forgot and I can't find any tutorials online. I just want to know how to move two vertexes, on opposite sides of each other, outwards/inwards from one another.

[image]

if i scale it does this

[image]

I know this is INCREDIBLE easy but I'm pulling a blank here.

Comment: Change your pivot point (center top of 3D viewport) to "individual origins", then scale.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to scale them on a specific axis.
Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale then <kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>Y</kbd>/<kbd>Z</kbd> to specify the axis

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "brings them in multiple directions". Another thing it's just completely un-understandable. At least put on some kind of illutration if you can't add the image of the model. Edit the question and add the details there

Comment: Sorry I was not specific enough. I have 2 vertexes on each side, if I scale them it brings them in multiple directions. lets say these are my vertexes ( :_____ : ) I want them to do this  ( :_: ) but they do this if I scale them ( "" )

that's my best recreating of what's happening cause I cant figure out how to put images in a comment lol

Comment: Edit the question, not the comment. Use this button under the Question, not the comment. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png

Comment: @Liam Check the updated answer